# How to get/set session data in Yesod handler tests?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is it possible to get session data from within a Yesod Handler test?
For example I'd like to get the current userId.

Later on, I'd also like to test two simultaneous browser sessions interacting with the Yesod app in turns.

[`getRequestCookies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-test-1.5.0.1/docs/Yesod-Test.html#v:getRequestCookies) does return the session, but in an encrypted state.

Comment: You should be able to call `makeSessionBackend` on your `App` value in order to get back a `Maybe SessionBackend` type, which you can call `sbLoadSession` on with a `Request` and a `UTCTime` to get a dictionary of unencrypted key-value pairs stored in the request. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.1.1/docs/Yesod-Core.html (not a Yesod user so this is all conjecture from looking at their source code)